# What should I do if the custom status code returns cors error?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

1. Returned in custom permission validation

```
// custom status code
context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(701);
```

2. Set up in the middleware

```
if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == 701 && httpContext.Request.Method != "OPTIONS")
{
    var body = new ResultDTO<string>()
    {
        Code = 701,
        MsgKey = "Jwt Token Expired",
        Message = "Jwt token expired, permission verification failed."
    };
    var bodys = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodys);

    await httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

3. error

```
// console
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM69HI8TSMUD", Request id "0HM69HI8TSMUD:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (0 of 54).
```

```
//http request
cors error
```

The reasons are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232876

And in the `ExceptionHandleMiddleware` the `try... .catche` cannot intercept

I need help
Required.
Custom status codes
Customize the return result

Comment: looks like there is some other code (such as in some  middleware) clears the response body or sets it to some new stream. Can you try putting your middleware at as later as possible in the pipeline? That should make your code override the others' and the issue will be fixed.